# What will be the best alternative to Curl in Python?

Tags: python, curl, urllib2, urllib

Curl has proved to be a good tool for testing Web API interfaces in the past.
I am now looking to emulate the same in Python with its urllib and urllib2 Modules. I was wondering if there is already a module written for this specific purpose.
Both Python 2 and Python 3 compatible solutions will work in my environment.

Comment: Maybe you want http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ ?

Comment: `requests.get, requests.post, requests.session` should be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

The Python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library is fantastic. I think it's much easier to use than urllib and urllib2.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Also this resource will be of great help to convert cURLs into [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

[Convert curl syntax to Python requests](https://curl.trillworks.com/)